# Drupal Multisite + Alias Suffix

Tags: drupal

I am actualy working on drupal multisite environment and I am stuck within a alias suffix problem.

I made a setup like this in my sites.php file for the Multisite Alias Names:

```
$sites['example.example.de'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-ref.example.example.de/vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-tst.example.example.de/vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-dev.example.example.de/vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-local.example.example.de/vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
```

My VHost Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/seu/xampp/htdocs/iptp"
    ServerName example.example.de
    ServerAlias tp-ref.example.example.de/vwp tp-tst.example.example.de/vwp tp-dev.example.example.de/vwp tp-local.example.example.de/vwp
</VirtualHost>
```

And my local host file:

```
127.0.0.1      example.example.de
127.0.0.1      tp-ref.example.example.de
127.0.0.1      tp-tst.example.example.de
127.0.0.1      tp-dev.example.example.de
127.0.0.1      tp-local.example.example.de
```

The URL example.example.de works without any problems, but when I am trying to open one of the other URLs, I could open the page, but Drupal seems to have a problem with the path.
For example, if i want to open the URL "tp-ref.example.example.de/vwp", Drupal trys to load all css and js files from "tp-ref.example.example.de", but it should load it from here "tp-ref.example.example.de/vwp".
I think this is a base path problem or something ... :/ Anyone got an idea how to workaround that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to serve your website from a subdirectory (/vwp) when the Drupal instance sits within the root of your VirtualHost, you need to create a `symbolic link` inside your project.

On Windows OS, you can do this with `mklink` command

First go to your document root

```
cd C:/seu/xampp/htdocs/iptp
```

Then create a symbolic link using `vwp` as name pointing to the document root of your project

```
mklink /D vwp C:/seu/xampp/htdocs/iptp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7

```
URL: http://dev.drupal.org
$sites['dev.drupal.org'] = 'example.com';

URL: http://localhost/example
$sites['localhost.example'] = 'example.com';

URL: http://localhost:8080/example
$sites['8080.localhost.example'] = 'example.com';

URL: http://www.drupal.org:8080/mysite/test/
$sites['8080.www.drupal.org.mysite.test'] = 'example.com';
```

According to this you should use:

```
$sites['example.example.de'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-ref.example.example.de.vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-tst.example.example.de.vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-dev.example.example.de.vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-local.example.example.de.vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but editing my sites.php as showed in the docs, I walked into another problem.
When I try to open for example "tp-ref.example.example.de/vwp" the website respons with "page not found" and redirects mit to "tp-ref.example.example.de" ...
The redirect is triggerd by a modul I use btw.